# Public folders - just a few won't replicate

Tags: exchange-2010, exchange-2007, exchange-migration

We're in the latter days of a 2007 -> 2010 migration for a fairly large org - about 12 Exchange servers total. The users mailboxes have (almost) all been moved to 2010, mailflow is (almost) entirely on 2010.

I've made replicas of all the Public Folders from the 2007 servers to a new 2010 server, just for public folder mailboxes. Replication was done over a week ago, and there's a handful of folders that won't complete replicating. We have ~500 public folders, and there's 6 remaining who's item count is far less than it's supposed to be. (I compared the output line-by-line of Get-PublicFolderStatistics against the 2007 and 2010 servers)

I've turned up 9001 Replication logging on the 2010 server to Expert. I do see a lot of this message during a replication run, but I also see a lot of successes : `An incoming replication message was processed.`  The error:

`Error -2147221233 reading property 0x67480014 on object type tbtReplication from database "2010PublicFolders".` [This appears to be harmless however.](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/225090) I'm not seeing any other errors on the 2010 server.

Any guesses, or next steps? To reiterate, I've got ~500 folders successfully replicated, but 6 that have a fraction of what they should.

Today, I added a single item to one of these PF on 2007, ran `Update-PublicFolder  "\MIS\MIS Contacts\Vendors" -server 2007Server`  and watched it replicate - the event viewer on each side shows the outgoing and incoming replication message. The only errors are the tbtReplication error listed above that is documented to be a false alarm.

The item count for this folder (using `get-publicfolderstatistics`) on 2007 is now 334, and on 2010 it's 1. So... it's updating some of the content but not all? Just new content? Not sure where to go next from here.

(As an aside, there are a few dozen folders that have an item count on 2010 that is 1 less than on 2007. Is that noise, or does it indicate another potential problem?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like each of the affected folders has some items that simply won't sync. I dialed the max replication message size down to 1 KB and tried adding each folder back into replication on the 2010 server and each folder would mostly replicate, so there's something in each folder that is crap.

I am not seeing any errors that indicate what is failing. Since 2007 is going away, I don't need to worry about a long-term fix. I simply made copies of each of the affected folder into my personal folders and will manually copy them into 2010 when I complete the migration. I'd like to look further into the cause and fix it, but I've spent too much time on this as it is.

Comment: Ok, so manual will be one way. If you happen across additional insights, such as the nature of 'crap', please share. We're doing a massive Public Folder migration this year and this question got me slightly worried.

Comment: Yes, it will be one-way. The 2007 public folders won't be used after I migrate all the mailbox databases to be using 2010, so one-way one-time is fine.